# Unable to set size in percent on multiple image background

Tags: css

I have a couple background images here:

```
html{
background: top left no-repeat url(http://wallpapers.pupazzo.org/animals/Peek-a-Boo_%20Red%20Fox%20Kit.jpg),
top right no-repeat url(http://www.dcwild.com/images/Fox-Kit-Riverfarm.jpg);
background-size: 50% 400px, 50% 400px;
}
```

The issue is when I try to set the y to `100%` it doesn't seem to work. The images seem to be getting the 100% measurement from something other than the entire page. Is there a way that I can have two images as the background and use CSS to position the images as `100%`?

Here is a fiddle for further example.

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/S2T7T/)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (though I'm not 100% certain!) you're saying that this doesn't work:

```
html{
    background: top left no-repeat url(http://wallpapers.pupazzo.org/animals/Peek-a-Boo_%20Red%20Fox%20Kit.jpg),
    top right no-repeat url(http://www.dcwild.com/images/Fox-Kit-Riverfarm.jpg);
    background-size: 50% 100%, 50% 100%;
}
```

This has a result that looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/S2T7T/2/).

If you set the `height` of `html` to `100%`, however, it works fine:

```
html {
    background: top left no-repeat url(http://wallpapers.pupazzo.org/animals/Peek-a-Boo_%20Red%20Fox%20Kit.jpg), top right no-repeat url(http://www.dcwild.com/images/Fox-Kit-Riverfarm.jpg);
    background-size: 50% 100%, 50% 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This has a result that looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/S2T7T/1/).